# ¿La etiqueta input puede tener el atributo type="text" por defecto?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una duda. La etiqueta `<input>` puede tener diferentes valores como `type="range"` ó `type="email"`. Entonces, ¿la etiqueta `<input>` puede tener el valor o atributo `type="text"` **sin mencionarlo**, es decir, por defecto?.

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="text">
```

¿es lo mismo que?

```
<input>
```

Mi problema es que tengo este código y lo que quiero es que el código *CSS* afecte a la etiqueta que no tiene ningún atributo, considerada como `<input>`, pero que dicho código *CSS* no afecte a otros *inputs* tales como `<input type="range">`

```css
input[type="text"] {
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 3):

Si revisamos la [especificación](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html) veremos como los inputs ofrecen por defecto *control de texto*, es decir aunque no le declares dicho atributo ese será el valor inicial que tome.

Por otro lado te estás complicando demasiado para hacer la selección del elemento deseado; por que:

- Un elemento o etiqueta HTML puede tener mas de una clase
- Puedes asignar una segunda clase al elemento que deseas afectar
- Hacer la selección de dicho elemento solo por la segunda clase asignada

Ejemplo:

```html
      <style>
        .aqui {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input class="elementos">
    <input type="text" class="elementos aqui">
    <input type="text" class="elementos">
    <input type="text" class="elementos">
    <input type="text" class="elementos">
```

En el ejemplo puedes observar que:

- Aplico la clase `aqui` solo el elemento que deseo afectar
- No se hace necesaria la selección en CSS por medio de atributos
- Pudieramos tener otro input de tipo text en el futuro al cual NO deseamos afectar y una regla de selección poco clara pudiera afectarlo también

Answer (score 0):

Así es, el valor por defecto de `<input>` es el tipo `"text"`, como bien se indica [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp#:%7E:text=The%20type%20attribute%20specifies%20the,default%20type%20is%20%22text%22.):

> El tipo de atributo especifica el tipo de elemento `<input>` a mostrar
> Si el tipo de atributo no se especifica, el tipo por defecto es `"text"`.